# Prevent Application from Fiddler Interception

Tags: asp.net

How I can prevent my HTTPS site from Fiddler interception? As Fiddler can even intercept HTTPS traffic.

Comment: There are several tools and software/hardware appliances that can intercept HTTPS traffic... even if you could prevent Fiddler (which I doubt!) it would not really help. what is your goal exactly ? why do you want to prevent interception ?

Comment: Sounds like he has a design issue, where too much sensitive data is sent over the wire to the client side.

Comment: If you own the server *and* the client, you can invent your own protocol over form values. It won't be 100% secure, but it won't be as easy as is with fiddler today.

Answer (score 4):

There's not much you could do from the website to prevent this from happening. Fiddler runs on the client and if the user has sufficient privileges to run it, this is out of your control as a web developer.

Comment: How how I can prevent sensitive informations being exposed to Client?

Comment: Do not send sensitive information to the client. Sensitive information should be stored on the server.

Comment: You will have to provide much more background about your application and what kind of sensitive information you are trying to use.

Comment: Say I am posting a form with username and password. So that information is submitted from client.Fiddler can intercept that. What is the solution?

Comment: I don't think that there is much you could do to prevent this from happening. Sorry.

Comment: @user1672097 The operative phrase is **never trust the client** so the one thing I will add is that you should **validate** whatever data you get from the client since as already accurately stated, you **cannot** possibly control the client nor what applications are running on it. In the scenario above, the client is intercepting **it's own submitted data** - not any other client - so at least it's "value" is somewhat diminished. Fiddler is an excellent tool that most Windows developers have and use extensively.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: there's not a lot you can do.

Long answer: Fiddler intercepts SSL traffic by creating a certificate that looks like the site you are talking to.  To do this, the user of Fiddler must [install a trusted certificate authority](http://fiddler2.com/documentation/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/TrustFiddlerRootCert).  Once this CA is installed on the Fiddler proxy is able to create "trusted" SSL certificates that look like they come from any site.

If you do not have control over the client infrastructure then there is nothing you can do.  If you do, you can prevent people from installing trusted certificate authorities.

Some of the larger sites (www.google.com) are able to implement [certificate pinning](https://owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning#What_Is_Pinning.3F), but this requires specific application support and is unlikely to work for you.